# Rails check_box_tag keep checked state (if checked) after page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I'm following [this guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/save-multiple-checkbox-values-database-rails/) for multi-checkbox in rails. I am using Rails 3 conventions, so I still have attr_accessible instead of strong parameters. Everything seems to work fine except I get this error:

> undefined method `match' for []:Array

userprofile.rb model:

```
class Userprofile < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save do
    self.expertise.gsub!(/[\[\]\"]/, "") if attribute_present?("interest")
  end

  attr_accessible :interest, :user_id, :country, :state_prov, :city
  serialize :interest, Array
```

userprofiles_helper.rb:

```
module UserprofilesHelper
  def checked(area)
      @userprofile.interest.nil? ? false :      @userprofile.interest.match(area)
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<h3>Area of Interest</h3>

  <%= label_tag 'interest_physics', 'Physics' %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'userprofile[interest][]', 'Physics', checked("Physics"), id: 'interest_physics' %>

  <%= label_tag 'expertise_maths', 'Maths' %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'userprofile[interest][]', 'Maths', checked("Maths"), id: 'interest_maths' %>
```

If I remove the checked helper method, then the checkbox value does not persist. I've been trying to fix the undefined method 'match' error. Or find an alternate way to keep the correct checkbox value checked when I edit the form.

Any suggestions would help, thank you!

Comment: A note on that guide you are using: The top of the guide states that the example you are following is an [Anti-Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). The guide under "The Right Way" is a much better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Userprofile#interest` is an array, it looks like you actually want to use `include?` in your helper instead of `match`. So in userprofiles_helper.rb:

```
  def checked?(area)
    @userprofile.interest.present? && @userprofile.interest.include?(area)
  end
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Before this comment, I ended up doing this:   


`<%= label_tag 'interest_development', 'Development' %>
            <%= check_box_tag 'userprofile[interest][]', 'Development', @userprofile.interest.include?('Development'), id: 'interest_development' %>`

Which uses `include?` but was bulky in the code. I just tried adding the checked? method in userprofiles helper and it worked the same. Thank you!